# numpy: how to set precision printing poly1d

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, formatting

I want to set precision (more in general the format) when printing a polynomial. For example:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> beta = np.asarray([-3.61380614191654e-09, 2.489464876955e-05, -0.0836384579176789, 143.213931472633])
>>> p = np.poly1d(beta)
>>> p
poly1d([-3.61380614e-09,  2.48946488e-05, -8.36384579e-02,  1.43213931e+02])
>>> print(p)
            3             2
-3.614e-09 x + 2.489e-05 x - 0.08364 x + 143.2
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=8) # this has no effect
>>> print(p)
            3             2
-3.614e-09 x + 2.489e-05 x - 0.08364 x + 143.2
```

I would like to get, calling `print` with polynomial, something similar to:

```py
                 3                  2
-3.61380614e-09 x + 2.48946487e-05 x - 0.08363845 x + 143.21393147
```

[**Edit**]

I tried using `numpy.polynomial` as A. Donda suggest but I get a different behaviour:

```py
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20) 
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> beta = np.asarray([-3.61380614191654e-09, 2.489464876955e-05, -0.0836384579176789, 143.213931472633])
>>> p = np.polynomial.Polynomial(np.flip(beta))
>>> p
Polynomial([ 1.4321393147e+02, -8.3638457918e-02,  2.4894648770e-05,
       -3.6138061419e-09], domain=[-1,  1], window=[-1,  1])
>>> print(p)
poly([ 1.4321393147e+02 -8.3638457918e-02  2.4894648770e-05 -3.6138061419e-09])
```

printing the polynomial using `print(p)` does not give me the expected result

[**Edit2**]

Ubuntu 20.10 has numpy 1.18.4. Instead, forcing a newer version (1.20.1) using pip3, I get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The [`__str__` method of `poly1d`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1579c9c21edf1723a0b125d309d2f66370c17e38/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L1259) uses a custom function to format numbers:

```
def fmt_float(q):
    s = '%.4g' % q
    if s.endswith('.0000'):
        s = s[:-5]
    return s
```

So, you are right, it is not influenced by NumPy's `printoptions`.

But the [documentation for `poly1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) says that it is "part of the old polynomial API" and one should better use [`numpy.polynomial`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html):

```
>>> p = np.polynomial.Polynomial(np.flip(beta))
>>> p
Polynomial([ 1.432139e+02, -8.363846e-02,  2.489465e-05, -3.613806e-09], domain=[-1,  1], window=[-1,  1])
>>> print(p)
143.213931472633 - 0.0836384579176789·x¹ + 2.489464876955e-05·x² - 3.61380614191654e-09·x³
```

The `np.flip` is necessary because other than `poly1d`, `Polynomial` expects the coefficients by increasing order.

That seems to solve your concrete problem, getting the coefficients in high precision. However, `Polynomial.__str__` still doesn't respect `printoptions`:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
>>> print(p)
143.213931472633 - 0.0836384579176789·x¹ + 2.489464876955e-05·x² - 3.61380614191654e-09·x³
```

You could file an issue on the NumPy repository.